# VsDebuggerCasualityData

Tags: wcf, w3wp

I have a .net 2.0 app on a win2003 VM that calls a WCF service hosted in IIS7 on a win 2008 VM. After developing the client and service and testing (all was good) I took the opportunity to take a snapshot of both VMs.

I come back to the VMs two weeks later and when I make the WCF call from the client I get a message dialog on the win 2008 server with the caption "Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger". The dialog then reads "An unhandled Microsoft .Net Framework exception occurred in w3wp.exe etc.

I take a look at the WCF service log an now see the following in the "WebHeaders" element:
"VsDebuggerCausalityData" AwAAAOEhpa2...lots of AAA

I've tried reverting both VMs to the previous snapshot but get the same problem.

In the WCF service trace file, I can see the logs entries from just before I took the snapshot and the request / response messages look perfect.

Could anyone please advise next step for diag and fix?

Many thanks

Rob.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to invoke WCF from wevservice studio. If you can do it , the problem 
   is in server.
2. If problem is in server , you can trace where exactly do you fail
   Trace can be done using 
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx

Comment: I can invoke the service from a local client installed on the win 2008 server. Problem only comes when trying to invoke from the client on win 2003 server.